# Transfer large packets in UDP

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, udp, large-data

Hi thanks for reviewing my question, I am trying to transfer large packets using simple UDP sockets in C. OS is windows 10; IDE Visual Studio.
System build-up:

1. UDP client - Send 6250 packets of 8K.
2. UDP server - receive  8K packets count them, and print to the screen.

When I run the server and start to receive packets, I succeed to receive between 1500-2000 packets the rest are seen in WireShark but my program lost them.

I know that it can be that the sender side is writing much faster than the server reads but it looks like a large amount of packet loss.
How can I improve or change my server-side code to be able to stand the rate?
Server code:

```
SOCKET s;
struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
int slen, recv_len;
uint8_t buf[BUFLEN] = {0} //8200B buffer;       
WSADATA wsa;
slen = sizeof(si_other);
int countwrite = 0;

printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Initialised.\n");

if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
}
printf("Socket created.\n");

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

//Bind
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
puts("Bind done");
while (1)
{
    printf("Waiting for data...");
    fflush(stdout);

    //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
    memset(buf, 0, BUFLEN);
    //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
    if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, &slen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    countwrite += 1;
    printf("Packet Number : %d\n", countwrite);
}
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: If the shown code is all your server is doing, then there's really nothing more you can do to improve its receive rate. Your receive-loop doesn't to anything expensive at all.

Comment: Get rid of the `printf()`s, and the `flush()`, which are slowing you down to console I/O speed, and the `memset()` which you don't need.

Comment: NB There are no jumbo packets here, or in IPV4. IPv6 has them but they are far larger than 8K.

Comment: UDP is intended for small individual packages. There is no guarantee you receive them in the same order as they were sent. If packets are lost underway they will not be retransmitted and the receiver will not be notified. So maybe you should really evaluate if UDP is actuallt right for what you are trying to do.